# Copy line from one MT4 chart to another

Tags: mt4

I would appreciate help to copy a line from one MT4 chart to another programatically. If I draw a line on a one hour time frame I would like the line to be recreated on my 15 min chart time frame as well as my 1 min time frame.  So I have three charts and drawing a line on the one chart should recreate the line on the other two charts as well. The line that I draw on my 1 hour time frame will be drawn with a mouse rather than the line being drawn programatically.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the answer:

```
void OnChartEvent(const int id,
                  const long &lparam,
                  const double &dparam,
                  const string &sparam)
  {
//---
   long lNextChartID = 0, lSecondChartID = 0;
   datetime dtOpenTime,dtCloseTime;
   double dOpenPrice,dClosePrice;

   if(id==CHARTEVENT_OBJECT_CREATE)
      {
         if(ObjectType(sparam) == OBJ_TREND)
         {
            lNextChartID = ChartNext(ChartID());
            lSecondChartID == ChartNext(lNextChartID);

            dtOpenTime = ObjectGet(sparam,OBJPROP_TIME1);
            dtCloseTime = ObjectGet(sparam,OBJPROP_TIME2);
            dOpenPrice = ObjectGet(sparam,OBJPROP_PRICE1);
            dClosePrice = ObjectGet(sparam,OBJPROP_PRICE2);      

            if(ChartSymbol(lNextChartID) == ChartSymbol(0) &&
               ChartPeriod(lNextChartID) < ChartPeriod(0))
            {
               ObjectCreate(lNextChartID,sparam + "1",OBJ_TREND,0,dtOpenTime,dOpenPrice,dtCloseTime,dClosePrice);
            }   
         }
      }
  }
```